# How to check if all the entries in columns of a matrix are equal (in MATLAB)?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of growing length for example a 4-by-x matrix A where x is increasing in a loop. I want to find the smallest column c where all columns before that, each, carry one single number. The matrix A can look like:

```
A = [1 2 3 4;
     1 2 3 5;
     1 2 3 1;
     1 2 3 0];
```

where `c=3`, and `x=4`.

At each iteration of the loop where `A` grows in length, the value of index `c` grows as well. Therefore, at each iteration, I want to update the value of `c`. How efficiently can I code this in Matlab?

Comment: If you add columns to the end of `A`, `x` will still be 3. When and how will you update column 4?

Comment: Again, how does `c` change if column 4 does not change so that all elements in that column are the same value?

Comment: @beaker column 4 changes too, as the matrix grows. For example, by the time x is 100, c can be 90. I'm not sure, if I've got your point right. c is the index of the last all-equal column.

Comment: @Elnaz If your matrix is `4 by x` you only have 4 columns. Therefore it can never be the case that the first 90 columns are equal. (Just trying to explain why your question is confusing) Perhaps you have a matrix of size `r by x` instead? And it can grow arbitrarily?

Comment: @Elnaz Show us an example of the matrix `A` above growing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
c = find(arrayfun(@(ind)all(A(1, ind)==A(:, ind)), 1:x), 1, 'first');
```

This finds the first column where not all values are the same. If you run this in a loop, you can detect when entries in a column start to differ:

```
for x = 1:maxX
  % grow A

  c = find(arrayfun(@(ind)~all(A(1, ind)==A(:, ind)), 1:x), 1, 'first');
  % If c is empty, all columns have values equal to first row.
  % Otherwise, we have to subtract 1 to get the number of columns with equal values
  if isempty(c)
    c = x;
  else
    c = c - 1;
  end

end
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. I initialize A with all zeros and this gives me the last all-zero column, where there are non-equal columns before that.

Comment: I do not want the last all-equal column. For example, A can have 100 columns for which columns 1 to 89 are all-equal ones. I want x=89.

Comment: If you use the suggestion under 'edit', you will the find the first column that differs. If you subtract 1 from that number, you will get `x`. Of course the result will be empty if there are no columns with differing values.

Comment: yes, thank you, but I cannot afford a loop since the length is huge.

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite the question. As it is it implies you are growing `A` in a loop. But if you are not, the line given under the edit should produce the desired result.

Comment: @ zeeMonkeez, oh, so you mean in the code above the edit, the for loop is imitating my loop or I should add it inside my loop?

Comment: @Elnaz indeed. Your growing code goes where the commented out line is. Then you test. Note that I specifically changed the code to only take into account the first `x` columns.

Comment: I corrected a mistake in my code. Also, "printf" is not MATLAB.

Comment: Sorry. I meant `fprintf`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you had the matrix `A` and you wanted to check a particular column `ii`to see if all its elements are the same. The code would be:

```
all(A(:, ii)==A(1, ii)) % checks if all elements in column are same as first element
```

Also, keep in mind that once the condition is broken, x cannot be updated anymore. Therefore, your code should be:

```
x = 0;
while true
    %% expand A by one column

    if ~all(A(:, x)==A(1, x)) % true if all elements in column are not the same as first element
        break;
    end
    x = x+1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a try as well:

```
% Find the columns which's elements are same and sum the logical array up
c = sum(A(1,:) == power(prod(A,1), 1/size(A,1)))
d=size(A,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the last column such that each column up to that one consists of equal values:

```
c = find(any(diff(A,1,1),1),1)-1;
```

or

```
c = find(any(bsxfun(@ne, A, A(1,:)),1),1)-1;
```

For example:

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4 5 6;
        1 2 3 5 5 7;
        1 2 3 1 5 0;
        1 2 3 0 5 8];
>> c = find(any(diff(A,1,1),1),1)-1
c =
     3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this (easy and fast):

```
Equal_test = A(1,:)==A(2,:)& A(2,:)==A(3,:)&A(3,:)==A(4,:);
c=find(Equal_test==false,1,'first')-1;
```

You can also check the result of find if you want.

Comment: It is mentioned that A is a column wise growing matrix

Comment: @Lati So you must compare the rows!!! I can not figure out why do you vote down the answer!!!

Comment: yes, in this case it works, I didn't actually try it, sorry. But if you would have, let's say 100 rows, it would be quite painful to write all the logical tests in your equation. And that's not me who down-voted and, more than one exclamation doesn't mean anything indeed.